# Fit equation with long fraction in two column setting

Tags: equations, fractions, longdivision

I have a an equation with a long fraction and at each derivation step the fraction gets longer and the final fraction looks something like this :

```
    \begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\frac{\sum_{A} P(Y|C= B, Y, G = H, A, K=0) P(Y, X < R, A)P(Y, X < R, A)P(C= Z | Y, W > K, A, U=0) P(Y, X < R, A)}{\sum_{A} P(T = K| A,S < Q A, W=0) P(N = K, A)P(N = K, A)P(N = K, A)P(N = K, A)}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

I am on two column setting and have viewed a couple of posts where they were able to break the fraction either because it has a short dominator or it contains summation that can be broken into multiple lines like in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370629/an-extremely-long-equation-with-fraction), [here2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545711/extremely-long-equation-with-large-fraction), and [here3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277711/correct-typesetting-of-a-formula-with-a-long-fraction). But in my case I am summing over the products in the nominator and dominator.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mathtools` package, a superset of the `amsmath` package, provides a macro called `\splitfrac`, which can be nested, and lets users split long numerators and/or denominators into shorter, stacked parts. For the fraction at hand, it looks like applying 3 nested `\splitfrac` directives to the numerator (for a total of four rows) and 2 nested `\splitfrac` directives to the denominator (for a total of three rows) will get the job done.

Optionally, encase both the numerator and the denominator in `\left( ... \right)` pairs.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \splitfrac
\let\P\relax % undefinet the `\P` macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{P} % probability operator

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{%
   \left(
   \splitfrac{\sum_{A} 
   \P(Y\mid C= B, Y, G = H, A, K=0)}
   {\splitfrac{\P(Y, X < R, A)
   \P(Y, X < R, A)}
   {\splitfrac{\P(C= Z \mid Y, W > K, A, U=0)}
   {\P(Y, X < R, A)}}}
   \right)
   }{%
   \left(
   \splitfrac{\sum_{A} 
   \P(T = K\mid A,S < Q A, W=0)}
   {\splitfrac{\P(N = K, A)\P(N = K, A)}
   {\P(N = K, A)\P(N = K, A)}}
   \right)
   }
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[1][1-5] % some filler text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked great.

Comment: @Moh - You're most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce named terms, and split things up

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X


   \begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\frac
  {\sum_{A} P(Y|C= B, Y, G = H, A, K=0) P(Y, X < R, A)P(Y, X < R, A)P(C= Z | Y, W > K, A, U=0) P(Y, X < R, A)}
  {\sum_{A} P(T = K| A,S < Q A, W=0) P(N = K, A)P(N = K, A)P(N = K, A)P(N = K, A)}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}


\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{align*}
   &\frac{n}{d}\\
\intertext{where}
  n&=\sum_{A}
  \left(\begin{aligned}
   &P(Y|C= B, Y, G = H, A, K=0)\\
   &P(Y, X < R, A)P(Y, X < R, A)\\
   &P(C= Z | Y, W > K, A, U=0)\\
  &P(Y, X < R, A)
   \end{aligned}\right)\\[5pt]
  d&=\sum_{A}
   \left(\begin{aligned}
  & P(T = K| A,S < Q A, W=0)\\
   &P(N = K, A)P(N = K, A)\\
   &P(N = K, A)P(N = K, A)
   \end{aligned}\right)
\end{align*}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I also have some long equations without fractions and will do it the way you illustrated. Thanks again